# How to put a property class as a variable in php?

Tags: php

So hi, I'm actually a very very beginner and i'd like to know how to set a property that is in a class as a variable to do condition?

```
class Utilisateur
{
public $mdp, $nom;
   function mot($mdp)
   {
     if (strlen($mdp)<=8) 
     {
      echo "Votre mot de passe n'est pas fort. ";
     }
   }
}
```

So the property i want to set as a variable is $mdp, but i'm not sure if i can really do this.
Thanks for your future replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might typically do would be to assign the variables as parameters to the class constructor and define them as properties within the class - allowing access afterwards using `$this->var` style syntax

```
class Utilisateur{
    public $mdp;
    public $nom;
    
    public function __construct($mdp=false,$nom=false){
        $this->mdp=$mdp;
        $this->nom=$nom;
    }

    function mot(){
        if ( strlen( $this->mdp ) <= 8 ) {
            echo "Votre mot de passe n'est pas fort.";
        }
    }
}

$obj=new Utilisateur('banana','fred');
$obj->mot();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i don't understand why you have to put a construct function with the variable that are set in false?

Comment: that just gives the variables a defined, default value - can be anything you wish. It also means that with suitable default values the `class` can be instantiated with no parameters at runtime... ie: `$obj=new Utilisateur;` would still have 2 properties `mdp` and `nom` both set as `false` ( or whatever value was used for the  default )